# Reponse Failed in nodejs. How to handle properly

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Cases:

When i insert the data in database through nodejs service. Data Insert successfully in Database(like mysql)

But response failed(for example client call **insert service** data successfully stored in database. but response failed for network problem anything, client don't know data inserted or not)

So How to handle above case properly?

Comment: Please post the code and error you are getting

Comment: Please see this post to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example -  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi vivek i n't face this problem. suppose get error like above question

how to handle?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bit wide for answer , but still I think , this is might be what you are looking for

```
model.User.create({your_data})
.then(user => { // if all goes right the this block will be executed

}).catch(err => { // if anything goes wrong this block will be executed
    console.log(err);
    // from here you can send err in response OR redirect to error page
})
```

Comment: exactly above code is like my code but i denote client means android application or other desktop application when they are called insert service only disconnect node service and android application .

not DB and nodejs.